# Variable type changes from a function to an other, goes from 'str' to 'NoneType'

Tags: python, binary-tree, huffman-code

As part of a school assignment I have to code the Huffman algorithm and I have an issue with one of my variables and I do not understand why.

```py
def encodedata(huffmanTree, dataIN):
    """
    Encodes the input string to its binary string representation.
    """
    binresult = ""
    for i in dataIN:
        tmp = _encodedata(huffmanTree, i, '') # NoneType ??
        binresult = binresult + tmp
    return binresult

def _encodedata(tree, char, val):
    if tree.key == char:
        return val # val is str
    if tree.key == None:
        _encodedata(tree.right, char, val + '1')
        _encodedata(tree.left, char, val + '0')
```

In my secundary function, val is a string (used type(val) to be sure) yet in my main function tmp is of type 'NoneType' while it should be the same as val...

**EDIT**: 
I changed my entire funtion and it works. Here is the version that I will submit:

```py
def encodedata(huffmanTree, dataIN):
    """
    Encodes the input string to its binary string representation.
    """
    result = ''
    L = _encodedata(huffmanTree, '', [])
    for i in dataIN:
        for j in L:
            if i == j[0]:
                result = result + j[1]

    return result

def _encodedata(tree, val, L):
    if tree.key != None:
        L.append((tree.key, val))
    else:
        _encodedata(tree.right, val + '1', L)
        _encodedata(tree.left, val + '0', L)
    return L
```

However I would still appreciate an explenation to why my previous code does not work. Thank you for those who helped.

Comment: you're missing the return on the second if branch

Comment: `_encodedata` doesn't explicitly `return` anything from the second `if` branch, so it returns `None`. What exactly did you expect it to return, and why?

Comment: @tripleee Try to be a little nicer. OP might not be aware completely of recursive functionality - they probably expected the `return val` to pass back to `tmp`

Comment: @tripleee by main I meant encodedata, as for the calling, I test them in an other file with tests I was given

Comment: for me tmp should equal val
in _encodata, the second if works as a recursion, it is not meant to return something unless when called tree.key == char and then it would return the wanted output (sorry if not clear, english is not my native language)

Comment: @Oerouxa: What is the type of `huffmanTree`, and how do you call `encodeData()` originally?

Comment: @quamrana huffmanTree is a binTree, I call encodedata with a functionning huffman tree and the string that was used to create the tree

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of your recursive calls:

```
def _encodedata(tree, char, val):
    if tree.key == char:
        return val # val is str
    if tree.key == None:
        return _encodedata(tree.right, char, val + '1')
        return _encodedata(tree.left, char, val + '0')
```

By not doing so, you implicitly return `None` in the function after the recursion is complete.

Comment: You can't `return` twice; it's unclear what the OP expects this to `return`, but this probably won't be correct.

Comment: I tried it and it works now for only one leaf of my tree, the one at the extreme right. However the rest still shows 'NoneType'